# how String.Format of RadGrid(Telerik) Sum result in footer?

Tags: telerik, footer, radgrid, string.format

my radgrid column like below :

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Benefit" DataField="Benefit"
                    HeaderText="Benefit" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Benefit" FilterImageToolTip="Filter">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBenefitInsideGrd" runat="server" Font-Size="11px" Text='<%# (bool)Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Benefit")) ? "<span class=\"lblInsideGrd\">Empty</span>" : String.Format("{0:#,0 Dollar;#,0- Dollar}", Eval("Benefit")) %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

how can i String.Format(reformat) Sum result in footer for this template column ?
mean i want something like {0:#,0 Dollar;#,0- Dollar} in output...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below link solved my problem :

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/aggregates/defaultcs.aspx

```
/// <summary>
/// The MasterTableView.DataBinding event is used to preserve the applied formatting to
/// data values in the column aggregate and still be able to add the name of the currently
/// selected aggregate function.
/// </summary>
protected void MasterTableView_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridNumericColumn unitPriceCol = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("UnitPrice") as GridNumericColumn;
    unitPriceCol.FooterAggregateFormatString = unitPriceCol.Aggregate.ToString() + ": {0:C}";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add an additional Format argument to the Eval function:

```
Eval("Benefit", "{0:#,0 Dollar;#,0- Dollar}")
```

Comment: Not sure of the example above works, but I have successfully done things like `Eval("id", "http://myurl.aspx?id={0}")`

Comment: devin thanks for answer , but i am looking for a way about formatting sum result in the footer (not each Benefit column in RadGrid)-> where should i put this eval in the upper codes ?

Comment: You can try the `FooterAggregateFormatString` property of the TemplateColumn, or use the `Eval` trick in the `FooterTemplate`